# Event handler keypress loading at beginning of page instead of on input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an HTML input box and want to use jQuery to get the value of user input as it is entered, however the DOM seems to be activated upon page load and it never takes the value of the input box as the user types it in. I'm new to this and can't figure out what I'm doing incorrectly, any ideas would be appreciated!

```
<input id="textFilter" type="text">

function addEventHandlerForSearch() { //Javascript Handler
  $('#textFilter').val();
  $('#searchText').text($('#textFilter').val());
  let searchVal = $('#searchText').text();

  $(document).ready(function() { // DOM
    $('#textFilter').keypress(addEventHandlerForSearch());
    loadSavedRunkeeperTweets().then(parseTweets);
  });
```

Comment: Show HTML and CSS code and make it all runnable on stackoverflow.

Comment: $(document).ready and addEventHandlerForSearch() should be 2 separate function.

Answer (score 0):

Simple vanilla implementation to get the value of the text box as it is typed would be:

```
const input = document.getElementById('textFilter');

input.onkeyup = () => {
    console.log(input.value)
}
```

Then you could do whatever you need to with that data. If jquery is a requirement, I apologize for not including that in my answer. Not my area of expertise lol.